# Can 良好 be used as a closing remark?

Tags: grammar, conversation

良好 is translated as be good, or be well in one of my dictionaries. This is a common closing remark in spoken English. Can 良好 be used in the same context in Chinese.

i.e.

```
OK, Bye now...
Take care, be well.
```

Are there instances where it might be used in closing an email (or the end of a letter)?

If these context are not correct please illustrate a situation where it would be appropriate to use this phrase.

Comment: No, 良好 sounds weird as a closing phrase in Chinese emails or letters. We would simply say 保重/祝好 for informal ones, and 此致敬礼/敬祝安好/即问近安 etc. for different formal cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

良好, 令人满意；好。should be translated as good or well without the "be," then it can be used anywhere good or well are used. I never heard it being used as a closing remark, but under some circumstances, such use is possible.

祝你的程序运行良好.--Wish your application runs well.

Source: http://baike.baidu.com/view/96755.htm